# What happens when a java class is annotated @WebService?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

A **WebService** Java class is same as normal class, but what is the **initialization** or **sequence** happens inside server or What actually server does internally when it looks up those classes?

Comment: Which server are we talking about?

Comment: I see your point, Since @WebService is similar to interface, so implementation might change between various servers. If that's your point then explaination for JBoss or WebLogic would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how does a simple class change to be a Web Service, if is that, the use o the @webservice notation enables the code injection that transforms your simple class in a servlet that will be answering http requests, and perform the desired @webmethod.

Comment: Yes, but is there a guide which explains how does it injects or configures it as servlet?